# Regex an unordered list, separated by different 'delimiters' in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to construct a regex to capture strings that match `\w{0,}?\s\d){0,}` i.e, a word followed by space then a number. I've mocked it up [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eusIiPw0JhrcqdkH)

The first N matches that are only separated by a comma are group 1.
The N matches after the string ' opt ', that are only separated by commas are group 2
The N matches after the string ' and/or ', that are only separated by commas are group 3

My attempt is this: `((\w+?\s\d),\s+(\w+?\s\d))*(\s+and/or\s+(\w+?\s\d))*(\s+opt\s+(\w+?\s\d))*`

```
Mind 3 opt Life 3, Prime 3 and/or Death 3 #This is not matched
Life 3, Mind 3 opt Prime 3 and/or Death 3 #This is matched
Life 3, Death 3 and/or Mind 3 opt Prime 3 #this is matched
```

But I'm sure there edge cases I'm not thinking of. And I fundamentally know this is order related, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`(?:|\s+and/or\s+|\s+opt\s+)((\w+?\s\d)(?:,\s+(\w+?\s\d))*)*`](https://www.regex101.com/r/kL4fL7/1)

You are looking for three separate scenarios:

`String starts with nothing` or `String starts with ' opt '` or `String starts with ' and/or '`

This is the same as:

```
(?:                     # Non matching group
    |                   # Nothing or 
    \s+and/or\s+|       # ' and/or ' or
    \s+opt\s+           # ' opt '
)                       # followed by
```

And then in each scenario you're looking for one or more lots of `(\w+?\s\d)` separated by a comma.

```
(
    (\w+?\s\d)          # a word followed by a single digit
    (?:,\s+             # preceeding comma and at least one space.
        (\w+?\s\d))*    # zero or more word-digit combinations as above,
)*                      # Any number of these
```

The explanation is much better on the above [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/kL4fL7/1).